# Redux useSelector is not updated fast enough

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I use redux with saga in my project, to make Axios requests in the store.
In order to give the user feedback about if the request has succeeded or not, I store an object in my store that holds two properties - `errMsg` and `isFetching`.

Whenever I make a request I set `isFetching` to true, and then if I the request is successful, I trigger a success action which changes `isFetching` to false.
I listen to `isFetching` changes in my component, if the last state of `isFetching` was false and now it changed to true, and there's no error message, then I trigger a success modal.

This implementation worked for me with a POST request, but when I tried it with a DELETE request, `isFetching` never changed to true.

I tried debugging redux, and saw that the two actions were happening and that the store was changing, but the effect in my component wasn't triggered.

I added a delay between the changing of `isFetching` to true, and then it worked.

Redux changes are too fast that useSelector isn't able to get the changes?
is there a solution for this?

(I'm sorry for explaining the code, my project is in a closed network and I can't copy code here, if the explanation isn't good enough, please tell me and I'll try to manually write the code)

**EDIT**:

Adding code example:

The listener for changes in `isFetching`:

```
 const { isFetchingDelete, errMsgDelete } = useSelector(
    (state: StoreState) => ({
      isFetchingDelete: state.students.deleteState.isFetching,
      errMsgDelete: state.students.deleteState.errMsg,
    })
  );

 const prevIsFetchingDeleteRef = useRef<boolean>();

.........
  useEffect(() => {
    // trying to log the value of isFetchingDelete here, always logs false
    if (!isFetchingDelete && prevIsFetchingDeleteRef.current) {
      if (errMsgDelete) {
        Swal.fire();
      } else {
        Swal.fire();
      }
    }

    prevIsFetchingDeleteRef.current = isFetchingDelete;
  }, [errMsgDelete, isFetchingDelete]);
```

The saga:

```
  function* deleteStudentHandler(action: ActionType<typeof deleteStudent>) {
    try {
      yield call(StudentsService.delete, action.payload);
      // if I add a delay of 1000ms here it's working
      yield put(deleteStudentSuccess(action.payload));
    } catch (e) {
      yield put(deleteStudentFailure(e.message));
    }
  }
```

my reducer:

```
  case: StudentsActionTypes.DELETE_STUDENT: {
    return {
      ...state,
      deleteState: {
        ...state.deleteState,
        isFetching: true
      }
    }
  }

  case: StudentsActionTypes.DELETE_STUDENT_SUCCESS: {
    return {
      ...state,
      students: [
        ...state.students.filter((student) => student.id !== action.payload),
      ],
      deleteState: {
        ...state.deleteState,
        isFetching: false,
      }
    }
  }
```

The code above works just fine on a post request that takes 300ms, but on a delete request that takes 2ms (json-server) it doesn't work.
Adding where I stated in a comment in the code, makes the code work.

Comment: I do not think that the changes in the store are too fast for the ``useSelector`` hook. Please provide some code which makes the problem reproducible.

Comment: @Tracer69 took a good 20 minutes but I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood why this was happening.

here, my problem was that StudentService.delete wasn't returning the Axios response, thus not returning a promise, and saga didn't have nothing to wait for..

```
  function* deleteStudentHandler(action: ActionType<typeof deleteStudent>) {
    try {
      yield call(StudentsService.delete, action.payload);
      // if I add a delay of 1000ms here it's working
      yield put(deleteStudentSuccess(action.payload));
    } catch (e) {
      yield put(deleteStudentFailure(e.message));
    }
  }
```

hopefully this helps other people that may encounter this problem.